# How do I generate a scroll in a container where the height will be variable?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have problems to visualize a responsive menu well. The data of the menu is dynamic, I can have from 2 items to 8, and when these exceed the maximum height (100%) they only show those that fit inside the container.

I tried to generate a scroll in the container, it works, but as long as I give it a height in pixels, but since the height of the table is dynamic, I give it 100% height, auto, and the scroll disappears.

How do I generate a scroll in a container where the height will be variable?

Comment: Please show your code here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 0):

you can make height of the container 100% but if container has parent and its parent has height in pixels like

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="scroll">
         <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

in style

```
.parent {
  height: 200px;
}
.scroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```